# MeteorJs 1.4 com erro ao adiciocar plataforma no windows 10

Tags: meteorjs

Estou tendo um erro ao tentar adicionar a plataforma do android e ao tentar instalar o sdk do android no meu app.
Estou tentando:
meteor install-sdk android
meteor add-platform android

Versao do meu MeteorJs 1.4 e já tenho instalado no pc o android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta ir no caminho, pelo prompt:

`C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\node_modules\is-my-json-valid`

e executar:

`meteor npm install is-property`

depois rodar no diretório do app:

`meteor add-platform android`

funcionou para mim.